# Statlib installation error (python 2.7) in windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, installation, pip

I have found the outputs as follows:

```
C:\Users\mm>python -m pip install statlib
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting statlib
  ERROR: ***Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement statlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for statlib***
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.3.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

How to solve the issue and run statlib?

Answer (score 0):

[statlib](https://pypi.org/project/statlib/) doesn't provide pip-installable files. It provides [direct](https://python-statlib.googlecode.com/files/statlib-1.1.tar.gz) [links](https://python-statlib.googlecode.com/files/statlib-1.0.tar.gz) but the links expired long ago. The package is no more, forget about it.